Search Console reports successful Page fetch on pages that do not exist
Here's a grammatically corrected version of your text:
Hi,
Almost 2 years ago, we migrated from Joomla CMS to Wordpress. On our old Joomla website, we used to have URLs such as:
mywebsite.com/cat1/art1/#!/ccomment

mywebsite.com/cat1/art1/?format=feed&type=atom

But after migrating to WordPress, we no longer have them. Now, in my Search Console, I'm seeing too many errors in the "Alternate page with proper canonical tag" section for these URLs.
When I inspect them in the URL Inspection tool, the result is as follows, and the Page fetch is successful:
URL is not on Google
This page is not indexed. Pages that aren't indexed can't be served on Google. See the details below to learn why it wasn't indexed. Learn more
Page changed?
info
Page indexing
Page is not indexed: Alternate page with proper canonical tag
Discovery
Sitemaps
Temporary processing error
Referring page
None detected
URL might be known from other sources that are currently not reported
Crawl
Last crawl
Apr 2, 2024, 10:25:21 AM
Crawled as
Googlebot smartphone
Crawl allowed?
Yes
Page fetch
Successful
Indexing allowed?
Yes
Indexing
User-declared canonical
info
mywebsite.com/cat1/art1/

How can I help Google understand that these URLs do not exist right now? Is Removals section of the search cosole a good way?

When you inspect the URL, do a live test. Then click the "View Tested Page" link, and then the More info tab of the drawer that opens. The data you need is in the HTTP Response and will tell you whether Google is receiving a 200 OK or a 404 not found response. Responding with a 404 is your best bet and should be handled in your server settings.
